# C++: Pointer to composite class data member

Tags: c++, pointers, member

Is it possible to access a composite class data member with pointers to members ? The following code is not valid but demonstrate the need.

For example:

```
class A
{
public:
    float fA;
};

class B
{
public:
    float fB;
    A a;
};

void test()
{
    // Use of member pointer to access B::fB member
    float B::*ptr = &B::fB; // -> OK
    B myB;
    myB.*ptr = 25.;

    // Use of member pointer to access B::a.fA member ???
    float B::*ptr2 = &B::a.fA; // -> ERROR
    B myB.*ptr2 = 25.;
}
```

I've complete my question here : [Pointer to composite class data member - Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881735/pointer-to-composite-class-data-member-part-2)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Why do you ask?

Comment: @6502 because it's a very unusual question, and with those its often the case that there's a completely different way to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no subclass here. A member of a member of B is not a member of B, and thus cannot be accessed with a pointer-to-member-of-B.

Comment: @ArneMertz : I've complete my question here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881735/pointer-to-composite-class-data-member-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious "reason" here is because `fA` is not a member of
`B`.  In this particular case, implementing it would probably
not cause any particular problems, both orthogonality rules, and
for member functions, I don't think it could be implemented.

What you can do, of course, is take the address of the `A`
member of `B`, then get to `fA` through it:

```
A B::*ptr = &B::a;
(myB.*ptr).fa = 25.;
```

, for example.  (I'm not sure that the parentheses are needed.
It's not a constrution that I use often enough to have the
precedences in my head.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with commenters, that probably you should ask how to do *what you want*, not how to do *what you think will do what you want* :)

As for the question: no, you cannot access `B::a.fA` in this way. However, you can do the following:

```
A myA;
float A::*ptr2 = &A::fA; // -> OK now
myB.a.*ptr2 = 25.;
```

Or the following:

```
A B::*ptr3 = &B::a; 
(myB.*ptr3).fA = 1.0f;  // -> OK too
```

Answer (score 0):

That is some weird looking syntax but if I understand you correctly, you are trying to access fA through class B. If that is the case, then you will need to create an instance of class B before class A is available to be accessed. Basically, if B doesn't exist, you can't access what is inside of it. The error is just what it sounds like, "left of .fA must have a class/struct/union" meaning your compiler can't figure out what is to the left of fA so the "a" is undefined or doesn't exist. Also, you have a redefinition error in there with B myB :)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot because the C++ syntax does not allow it. I don't see anything really special about what you're trying to do, but it's simply not considered in the language.

Note however that a pointer to data member is an object that given an instance will return a reference to a specific data member. You can implement this functionality manually relaxing the limitations:

```
struct A
{
    double x;
    double y;
    static double& x_of(void *p) { return ((A *)p)->x; }
    static double& y_of(void *p) { return ((A *)p)->y; }
};

struct B
{
    double z;
    A a;
    static double& x_of(void *p) { return ((B *)p)->a.x; }
    static double& y_of(void *p) { return ((B *)p)->a.y; }
    static double& z_of(void *p) { return ((B *)p)->z; }
};
```

The type of the pointer is just `double& (*)(void *)` and you can use this kind of trick even for example to return as member an element of an array.